# Using Pi 2 as a media center AND git server

Tags: ssh, openelec, xbian, git

I would like to use my Raspberry Pi 2 mainly as a media center but also as a private git server for small projects like LaTeX documents.

My goal is to be able to set this server as a remote repo to push to and pull from over the web with various interfaces (Linux shell, Windows Git-tortoise). On the other hand, I would like to prevent unauthenticated access to my home network and my Pi.

Since there are multiple ways of achieving this and I am not an expert regarding IT security, I would like to know if someone can recommend or has experience with a certain setup:

My first idea was to enable port-forwarding inside my router for SSH access to the Pi. This seems to work, however, I would have to change the default username and password, or anyone would be able to access the device. I would also have to create a new (somehow restricted) user account if I ever wanted to share the repo.

What other possibilities are there to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Welcome -- but this is *a Q&A site*, not a discussion forum. Very broad and/or open ended questions such as this one are not appropriate.   Please take [the tour](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) if you have not yet.  Singular, specific questions are fine, but you have a series of arbitrary ones, some of which (e.g., the capabilities of apache) are not pi-specific and hence off-topic here.  And yes, if you want to run a git server, you must install git server software.

Comment: I tried to narrow it down a bit, if it's still too broad, I will adressthe question to a different platform, no problem.

Comment: "Git server" is a misnomer - `git` is a distributed SCM and the contents of a repository are peer-shared/duplicated amongst all users - all it takes is a user, called perhaps "git" but that is not important with an account on the RPi and ssh access to it .  I keep a bare "mirror" repository (no local editable files, just the `.git` subdirectory) on a spare Laptop that I use for other things such as a IPv6 gateway.  I then push changes from my development machines out to it and fetch updates from it using the native `git` "ssh" handlers.

Comment: You are most likely right, when I wrote "git server", I meant it as "Server containing a remote bare git repository", which is about the same terminology used in the [official documentation](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).
But using your method would give full SSH control over the device to everyone interacting with this repository, while I would rather limit it to pushing und pulling.